# PHP - usort to order array list by provider with complex function

Tags: php, usort

I'd like to order the MyObject list (`$myObjectList`) by itemOrderList (*available in variable in example code*), as MyObject with no provider, MyObject with Gmail provider, MyObject with Hotmail provider, and other at the end.

```
private function reOrderByProvider(
    MyObject $actualObject,
    MyObject $nextObject
): int {
    $actual = array_search($actualObject->getProvider(), $this->itemOrderList);
    $next   = array_search($nextObject->getProvider(), $this->itemOrderList);

    if ($actual === $next) {
        return 0;
    }

    return (($next === false) || ($actual < $next)) ? -1 : +1;
}
```

The order list I should be respect is:

```
$this->itemOrderList = [null, 'gmail', 'hotmail'];
```

I have multiple object with Gmail provider, Hotmail provider, and some object aren't listed in list, these unlisted providers must be at the end of the sort.

For that, I use this PHP function `usort($myObjectList, [$this, 'reOrderByProvider']);`

Comment: If `$next === false` you always get `-1` which means `$nextObject` will come before `$actualObject` that sounds like the opposite of what you want. Ideally you want whichever object results in `false` to be after the other one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, I recommend to use some kind of **weights** for each provider, your sorting function can look like:

```
function reOrderByProvider(
    MyObject $actualObject,
    MyObject $nextObject
) {
    $weights = [
        null => 100, 
        'gmail' => 50, 
        'hotmail' => 25,
    ];
    $provider = $actualObject->getProvider();
    $actualObjectWeight = array_key_exists($provider, $weights) ? $weights[$provider] : 0;
    $provider = $nextObject->getProvider();
    $nextObjectWeight = array_key_exists($provider, $weights) ? $weights[$provider] : 0;

    return $nextObjectWeight - $actualObjectWeight;
}
```

Sample fiddle [here](https://3v4l.org/UWOqX).